# How can I install Ubuntu messaging menu on Mint?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, package-management

One thing I like about Ubuntu is the messaging menu. Can I add the ubuntu messaging menu to Mint 12?

Answer (score 3):

Installing software on Mint is relativity identical to most Debian based distributions.   I have not really used Mint, but I did test its ability to install Ubuntu packages in the past.  I'm sure its not exactly recommended to replace any critical packages, but it did work as expected.  From what I understand Linux Mint 12 is compatible with Ubuntu 11.10.

The package your referring to is called, `indicator-applet`.  It has been recently ported from Gnome2 to Gnome3, so it's not officially available for a release or two.  You can still install the package from a PPA, in this case the port developer runs a solid one.

Add the custom PPA, which has a copy of the new gnome3 `indicator-applet`.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jconti/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-applet indicator-applet-complete indicator-applet-session
```

If you also want the Global Menu indicator applet, for Gnome3 Classic, run this from terminal.

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-applet-appmenu
```

Here is a good link, for adding the applet, in Gnome3 Classic.
http://www.webupd8.org/2011/11/indicator-applet-ported-to-gnome-3-can.html

I'm not sure if Mint includes, `python-software-properties`, which provides `add-apt-repository`.  If not you need to `dpkg -i` a downloaded package from Ubuntu 11.10.  This was needed many releases ago, but I suspect Mint added PPA support by now.

Comment: yup it's the messaging menu. i'll give it a try and get back to you.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to get the package name for you, If for some reason its not available in your repos post back.

Comment: Did you attempt to install the package?  It really should be a quick procedure.

Comment: Get: Package indicator-applet is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'indicator-applet' has no installation candidate

Comment: I updated the answer, and added the package location.

Comment: So close now I think. Just can't see it in the gnome-tweak-tool to activate it. You know how to add it to the panel? Alt+right-click doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Not complete though...

Comment: I'm not sure how you go about adding the applet to the panel, but I suspect it would be in the same manner you normally make applet changes.  ..O wait, the applet is not in the list, where other applets are found?